# CListView in yii

Tags: listview, yii

please solve my problem
i m using Clistview like below

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                'id'=>'yii-list',
                'dataProvider'=>$model,
                'itemView'=>'_remark_list',
                //'template'=>'{pager}<div class="fleft"><b>{sorter}</b></div><div class="fright">{summary}</div><div class="clear"></div><div class="rightInner"><h1>Search Result</h1>{items}</div>{pager}',
                'enableSorting' => true,
                //'sortableAttributes'=>array(
                //  'email_id'=>'email_id',
                //),
                'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'function(id,data) {
                        $("a#manage-inline").fancybox({"scrolling":"auto","titleShow":false,"width":"850px","height":"500px"});
                    }',
                ));
```

I got error like this
Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object
in **dataProvider**

what to write in dataprovider.

THis is my controller

```
public function actionViewEmailLog($id, $layout=false)
    {
        $model          = EmailArchive::model()->findAll('email_id =:data', array(':data'=>$id));
        $this->layout   = false;
        $this->render('ViewEmailLog',array('model'=>$model));
    }
```

plz help me soon
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

From the controller, you need to pass to the view a data provider:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Model');

$this->render('index', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ));
```

Could you paste the action of your Controller which is rendering this view?

**Update:** after seeing the code of your controller, you have to call it like this:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('EmailArchive', array(
        'criteria' => array(
            'condition' => 'email_id=:id',
            'params' => array(':id' => $id)
    )));
$this->render('ViewEmailLog', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider));
```

Comment: Right, and in other words - you're passing the wrong data type to dataProvider parameter. See more here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView

Comment: I have updated my answer after seeing the code of your controller @uk123